# Ods output delete SAS System title

Tags: sas, ods

I have used an ODS output to PDf of a freq table inspite of using the noptitle it still prints SAS System on the top.

the code is

```
options nodate center nonumber ; 
ods noptitle ;

ods pdf file="Z:\temp.pdf" ;
ods proclabel="The totals";

proc freq data=compulsion;  
tables year; 
label year="year of the child";
;run;
ods pdf close;
```

But still I get the main title as "The SAS System", how to delete this title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use an empty title statement, that removes all manual or automatically assigned titles (simple but it works):

```
options nodate center nonumber ; 
ods noptitle ;
ods pdf file="Z:\temp.pdf" ;
ods proclabel="The totals";
title;/*<-reset all titles or overwrite it with wanted title*/
proc freq data=compulsion;  
tables year; 
label year="year of the child";
;run;
ods pdf close;
```

Edit for clarification: noptitle only removes the title generated by the proc, like "The FREQ Procedure". "The Sas System" is a not proc-related title

Comment: You'll still need `ods noptitle` to remove "The Freq Procedure" from the report heading

Comment: @Keith: Yes, forgot to add after copying the code, added it again, ty...